# GPU artifacts and computer freezes on boot

Tags: imac, performance, graphics, gpu

I have a rather strange situation, which I cannot interpret. I have an iMac 2011 27" with an upgraded GPU. This GPU displays occasionally diagonal stripes of artifacts and freezes. This usually happens when the machine is cold and I turn it on.

Artifacts are usually a sign of a failing GPU. What puzzles me is that I can use the computer for hours and run benchmarks such as Valley successfully, without any problems. But when I turn it on in the morning (room temperature 14ºC [~57ºF] and machine not much warmer) it can happen, that the computer displays those problems just after I log in.

I already documented myself on artifacts and would say that the GPU was properly cleaned and it has the right thermal paste applied (MX-4 + K-5PRO). It could be the VRAM ICs... I also read that power supplies can cause these problems.

I would like to know more about what is going on and where I can get more information about it.

Comment: I'm assuming the iMac does not generate these artifacts in warmer ambient temperatures. Since you discovered that a low ambient temperature seems to be the cause, is there any way you can reposition the iMac in the morning sun to warm it up that way? Perhaps a small space heater with an enclosed fan can be set up to warm the iMac before use. If you cannot try these remedies, perhaps just turning the iMac on and letting it generate some internal heat for 10 minutes before logging in may help.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I am actually trying to understand why that happens, since I am going to repair it and need to know what to check with an eventual replacement part. I am just puzzled, that it happens with a cold machine and not when it is in heavy use as I would expect.

Comment: To me, this indicates a physical defect whereby a trace or traces on a circuit board, or a solder connection of a component or components (chip/surface mounted unit, ribbon cable) on a circuit board has a minute break which only affects the electronics when the material shrinks caused by the lower temperature. Once warm, the break closes as the materials expand, and the electronics operate correctly. That is my hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks @IconDaemon. I thought about something similar. Difficult to track down!